# How to group rows and select top 1

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-ce

I am using a SQL Server CE database. I have a students fee table like :

Table **dues**:

```
Erno  |   Date     |  Due   
---------------------------
1       1-Jan-2016    220
1       1-Mar-2016    200   
1       1-Apr-2016    210   
1       1-May-2016    200
2       1-Jan-2016    250   
2       1-Feb-2016    300   
2       1-Mar-2016    220   
2       1-Apr-2016    200   
3       1-Jan-2016    300
3       1-Feb-2016    150   
3       1-May-2016    400
3       1-Jun-2016    300
```

where *ErNo* is Enrollment no. and *Date* is deposit date and *Due* is balance of amount or fee up-to that date.

I want to get the latest record of every `Erno` or `Student`.

Like :

Latest Due information :

```
   Erno        Date       Due
     1      1-May-2016    200   
     2      1-Apr-2016    200
     3      1-Jun-2016    300
```

Is there any SQL Server CE query to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  select fee.erno,fee.date,fee.due from dues fee 
    join 
    (select erno, max([date]) maxdate
        from dues group by erno) mx 
    on fee.erno = mx.erno and fee.date = mx.maxdate
    order by fee.erno
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `join` the table back to itself as I don't believe `row_number` is supported:

```
select sf.erno, sf.date, sf.due
from studentfee sf join (
    select erno, max(date) maxdate
    from studentfee
    group by erno) t on sf.erno = t.erno and sf.date = t.maxdate
```

Comment: Does it affect the performance ? Actually there are more than 80,000 rows  and about 20 fields in this table, like tax, charge, previousBal etc.

Comment: @ProgramAdmin -- Generally in regards to performance, it depends.  You would benefit from having an index on `erno` and `date` though.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
select sf.*
from studentfee sf
where sf.date = (select max(sf2.date) from studentfee sf2 where sf2.errno = sf.errno);
```

And then for performance, you want an index on `studentfee(errno, date)`.

Comment: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 18,Token in error = select ]